# cleaned_data not picking up updated integer values from form in django

Tags: django

I am a bit new to Django but was able to find all the answers for my problems except this one.

I wanted to submit a form that had both integer fields and text area fields
So with usual form submission, I was able to get data from the form and use the form.cleaned_data to save the form

When I wanted to update the same form I retrieved that specific table data and loaded it into form for easy changes.

But when I tried to resubmit the form by changing the values, the form was sending previous data of integer fields that I fed to form rather than the changed values.

But it is sending the updated text area values as usual.

This is the image when data is retrieved and fed into the form.
  [Before editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pTJS.png)

And this is After I editing the form[After editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMtCY.png)

printed request.post data after I submited the form with updated values
 It returns previous values rather than updated values

```
<tr><th><label for="id_Number_of_existing_programmes">Number of existing programmes:</label></th><td>
<input type="number" name="Number_of_existing_programmes" value="5" required id="id_Number_of_existing_programmes"></td></tr>
```

Here number is stored in value rather than inside the html tags with is usually the case with text fields
like this

```
<textarea name="Department_center" cols="40" rows="10" required id="id_Department_center">Like this</textarea>
```

The only solution that I can think is to not feed data that are Integer fields and only feed data that are text type into forms.

Is there any other option?

Model.py code

```
Number_of_existing_programmes = models.IntegerField()
```

Didn't add any widget inside the form.py for that field so it is default

```
class Criteria1_PhDForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = m.Criteria1_PhD
    exclude = ['Criteria1']
```

and code in views.py

for loading already submitted data

```
phd = f.Criteria1_PhDForm(instance=m.Criteria1_PhD.objects.get(Criteria1=criteria1_get))
```

request.post

```
phd = f.Criteria1_PhDForm(request.POST)
```

data retreival from db is fine and correct data is retreived but it isn't being changed when I resubmit it

request.post doesn't get updated data but the next code works as usual when text field data is updated

```
m.Criteria1_PhD.objects.filter(Criteria1=criteria1_get).update(**phd.cleaned_data)
```

Any help would be appretiated. Thanks

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without seeing your code. Django is quite capable of sending updated values for integer fields, so you are doing something to prevent it.

Comment: Added more code from mode, form and views file

Answer (score 0):

Found the root of the issue when I was doing more testing.

I was using different models that had the same field names

like this

```
class Criteria3_Major_projects(models.Model):
grade = models.IntegerField()

class Criteria3_Minor_projects(models.Model):
grade = models.IntegerField()
```

And apparently, the form was taking fields with the same name in the template like this

```
<td><input type="number" name="grade" value="547" required id="id_grade"></td>
```

and so all fields from different models have the same name so the request.post was talking the value from the last field of that name from the templates

All fields were getting updated when the last input field of that type and name was updated.

Hope my answer is clear.